# Meilisearch Invalid JSON: expected value at line 1 column 1

Tags: curl, meilisearch

I'm trying to load data into Meilisearch via CURL but keep getting the error:

`Invalid JSON: expected value at line 1 column 1`

I have run the JSON through a validator and the data pass so I decided to download the sample data from Meilisearch to double-check my own sanity (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meilisearch/MeiliSearch/master/datasets/movies/movies.json).

The test movie.json also passes validation but when I try and load it into Meilisearch I get the same error `Invalid JSON: expected value at line 1 column 1`.

Is it possible my CURL request is the problem?

```
curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:7700/indexes/products/documents' --data products.json
...
curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:7700/indexes/movies/documents' --data movies.json
```

**Steps to reproduce on Ubuntu 18.04 are as follows:**

1. Download and launch with Docker

```
docker run -it --rm \
    -p 7700:7700 \
    -v $(pwd)/data.ms:/data.ms \
    getmeili/meilisearch
```

2. Download the sample data

```
curl -X GET 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meilisearch/MeiliSearch/master/datasets/movies/movies.json'
```

3. Try and index the sample data

```
curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:7700/indexes/movies/documents' --data movies.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `@` in front of your `json` file

try this:

```
curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:7700/indexes/movies/documents' --data @movies.json
```